# Calculate real TQRMemo Height on QuickReport

Tags: delphi, quickreports

I have several memos with different font on QuickReport. Now I'd like to know the most bottom point for all (for set some shape below). How? If I calculate TextHeight for each and multiple by lines count (aMemo.ParentReport.TextHeight(aMemo.Font, 'W') * aMemo.Lines.Count), results are not correctly - QuickReport print lines like with strange height and position of my shape for some fonts are too high or too low.

Comment: Memo lines is a TStrings which is a list of strings and each string is displayed on a new line and can take up one or more lines visually depending on the WordWrap setting.

Comment: What do you mean under *most bottom point*? You want to know height (in pixels) of `TMemo` control or height (in pixels) of the text, placed in `TMemo`? I can't get what are you trying to do.

Comment: Brian, Diana: Not TMemo but T**QR**Memo. I have on one TQRBand several TQRMemo components. A know, what contains, but no height of text each. I need to know, where the printed text will end (vertical position). When I try to calculate by TextHeight, result is different from real after print.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got it. `TextHeight` cannot be call from QuickReport, but from `Printer.Canvas`. Then divide it by Y-Resolution for printer, next divide by 254 and multiple by 96. Result will be round and this is real value of Height of text in `TQRMemo`. All values are not accessible before print from QuickReport. It's very "smart" to return not real values based on same properties like during printing by component (by `TQuickRep.TextHeight` method).